# How to post 'multipart/form-data' content without file via python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to post password to server. Here's the server's source code(mainly):

```
<FORM ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" METHOD=POST> 
Password:<INPUT NAME="pw1" TYPE="password">
Password:<INPUT NAME="pw2" TYPE="password">   
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Confirm">
```

Below is my code:

```
import requests
url = 'http://192.168.0.1/pw'
file = {"pw1":"abc","pw2":"abc"}
r = requests.post(url, files = file)
```

From wireshark, I get:

```
--4d4bb99654064447b31a7afb787e5dbc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pw1"; filename="pw1"

abc
--4d4bb99654064447b31a7afb787e5dbc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pw2"; filename="pw2"

abc
--4d4bb99654064447b31a7afb787e5dbc--
```

What I expect is that there's no `filename="pw1"/"pw2"` i.e.,

```
--4d4bb99654064447b31a7afb787e5dbc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pw1"

abc
--4d4bb99654064447b31a7afb787e5dbc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pw2"

abc
--4d4bb99654064447b31a7afb787e5dbc--
```

The telegram can be recognized by server only in this way.
How to solve handle the post request? Do I have to use `files` if I want to use requests library in this case? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the form html you have posted, you dont have to send the input elements in files dict.
The following code snippet should work -

```
import requests
url = 'http://192.168.0.1/pw'
data = {"pw1":"abc","pw2":"abc"}
files = {'file': ''}
r = requests.post(url, data=data, files=files)
```

Comment: Yes it works. Thank you. From the guideline [here](http://www.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files), there's no such format as you posted. So is there a more detailed manual for a novice?

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. You can accept the answer then.